# fs.rmdir recursive stops working after app is packaged

Tags: node.js, zeit-pkg

fs.rmdir recursive stops working after app is packaged with Zeit/pkg

The following script works in 2 cases:

1. The script is ran unpackaged directly from node as node test.js and works perfectly
2. The script is ran packaged and the tmpDir is empty. (most remove/comment fs.appendFileSync line)

```
    const os = require('os');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');

    var tmpDir = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'test');
    if(!fs.existsSync(tmpDir)){
        fs.mkdirSync(tmpDir);
        fs.appendFileSync(path.join(tmpDir, 'message.txt'), 'data to append');
    }

    fs.rmdir(tmpDir, {recursive: true}, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('finished');
    });
```

Otherwise it returns the following error:

```
internal/validators.js:117
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Buffer
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:117:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:583:5)
    at isRootPath (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:168:26)
    at fs.readdir (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:850:18)
    at _rmchildren (internal/fs/rimraf.js:130:3)
    at internal/fs/rimraf.js:117:16
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:154:23) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Tested on node12 and 13 on Windows 10.

Anyone know of a solution to this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by including and using the `rimraf` package directly.

There's also the `Del` package and for a simpler solution there's this bit of code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var deleteFolderRecursive = function(path) {
  if( fs.existsSync(path) ) {
    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function(file,index){
      var curPath = path + "/" + file;
      if(fs.lstatSync(curPath).isDirectory()) { // recurse
        deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
      } else { // delete file
        fs.unlinkSync(curPath);
      }
    });
    fs.rmdirSync(path);
  }
};
```